# How to make a minutely cronjob on debian?

Tags: php, cron, debian

How to make a minutely cronjob on debian?

Can someone help me?

The "action" should be "php /var/www/cronjob/index.php"

i have no idea!

Comment: Cron works well down to one minute resolutions, but it fuzzes a bit around that mark. If it's important that it runs at the top of the minute very precisely, you may need to daemonize the PHP app in question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`*/N     *     *   *    *        /path_to_php/php /var/www/cronjob/index.php`

N - number of minutes. and you may need to specify full path to php (`/usr/local/bin/php` or whatewer)

Comment: In my experience you always need to specify the full path, especially if you're running as a user such as www-data. The path to PHP is /usr/bin/php by default on Debian.

Comment: @pwaring, thanks, i'm not very familiar to debian, so don't remember it's path

Comment: To make dealing with cronjob configuration easier, create a command on the shell which executes your PHP. This allows to change the details over time w/o changing the crontab, like a changed path to PHP or if you'd like to modify the php configuration of that task in specific. It will make the crontab easier to read as well.

Answer (score 6):

```
* * * * * php /var/www/cronjob/index.php
```

1: * = every minute

2: * = every hour

3: * = every day of month

4: * = every month

5: * = every day of week